# Fail to fetch internal api data in nextjs app deployed with amplify and AWS

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, next.js, aws-amplify, serverless

My Nextjs app is deployed on AWS x Amplify at https://<example.com> but the js console indicates it fails to fetch data from the internal api.

The endpoint is defined in this function in a Flux Store object.

```
  _getAssets = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API}/api/v1/assets`, {
        method: 'get',
        headers: {
          'Authorization': `Basic ${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_TOKEN}`,
        }
      })
      const assetsCall = await response.json()
      return assetsCall.data
    } catch(ex) {
      console.log(ex)
      return []
    }
  }
```

In my environment:

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_API=<example.com>
NEXT_PUBLIC_API_TOKEN=12345
```

The build script is `"next build && next export"`

The api call produces error 404.
In js console:

```
**GENERAL**
Request URL: <example.com>/api/v1/assets
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 404 
Remote Address: 13.35.13.120:443
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
**RESPONSE HEADERS**
age: 5524
cache-control: public, max-age=0, s-maxage=2678400, must-revalidate
content-encoding: gzip
content-type: text/html
date: Tue, 15 Mar 2022 05:31:29 GMT
etag: W/"a396cb2a54d64f73533333bfa2da1e6d"
last-modified: Tue, 15 Mar 2022 05:24:37 GMT
server: AmazonS3
vary: Accept-Encoding
via: 1.1 0b3572829f6f42309f3adfa694398770.cloudfront.net (CloudFront), 1.1 fb176da9df72832dd488674f28c0a880.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
x-amz-cf-id: g-I0JZ1hTHIfaL0yfGTX5c42i6wkxdRljRgRCD9Ei87lRb4KNsJo-w==
x-amz-cf-pop: SIN5-C1
x-amz-cf-pop: SIN5-C1
x-cache: Error from cloudfront
**REQUEST HEADERS**
:authority: <example.com>
:method: GET
:path: /api/v1/assets
:scheme: https
accept: */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
authorization: Basic 12345
referer: https://<example.com>/vest
sec-fetch-dest: empty
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
sec-gpc: 1
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 <blabla>
```

My questions:
Is it correct to define NEXT_PUBLIC_API as <example.com> (the frontend URL) in my environmnent, or should the api call another URL?

Why can't the app fetch data from the api? I haven't defined custom headers in customHttp.yml, do i need to write something in this file?

Comment: I think it is failing because of `CORS header`. I'm not sure but it could be the reason.

Comment: I tested commenting out `headers: {'Authorization': 'Basic ${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_TOKEN}',}` in `_getAssets` function, but still getting 404 error @DharmikPatel

Comment: You don't have to comment out headers, You need to add `CORS` header. Search it on google.

Comment: Is `_getAssets` being called from the client-side or server-side?